# Why create procedure requires a read on inode of new file before writing it?

Tags: operating-system, filesystems

I am studying operating systems from OPERATING SYSTEMS THREE EASY PIECES. In the section of file system implementation > new file creation.

While creating a new file, the OS requires a read on the inode of newly created file.

My question is why this read call necessary before the read when one can simply write to the inode?

[Screenshot from operating systems: three easy pieces by REMZI H. ARPACI-DUSSEAU and ANDREA C. ARPACI-DUSSEAU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ibx5.png)